# Is there a way to require a field based on another field using a Yup schema?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have a title (input field) and a checkbox. I've successfully implemented a schema to require the checkbox on its own. What I want to do is, validate if something has been typed in the title, if it's empty then the checkbox is required. I tried following Yup docs but I can't get anything to work.

I've tried this, but I don't get an error when the title isn't filled.

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
title: Yup.string()
.required('Required'),
checkbox: Yup.bool()
.when('title', ({ is: true, then: Yup.bool().required('Required') }))
});
```

And if possible, is there a way to validate a field using a state in my component instead?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Yup.ref()`.

```
 title: Yup.string().required('Title is required'),
 checkbox: Yup.boolean().nullable().required(Yup.ref('title'), "checkbox is required"),
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Is it because my elements aren't siblings? They're in the same scope/form but not direct siblings.